# web.config image to web page redirect in .Net?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config

Is there a `web.config` code I can use to redirect the url of an image to an actual web page?

What can I do to make it so when someone access an image via their address bar by typing in: http://www.sitename.com/images/1.jpg

It will instead redirect the user to the web page: http://www.sitename.com/view/1.html

I want to still be able to place the images in image tags though.

Comment: Should they see the image, then click on it to get redirected?

Comment: Yes, Click on image after redirect on page then they see image.

Answer (score 0):

Create Rewrite Rules as explained [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module). You can do it on the `IIS` manager. 
You will only need a regular expression for detecting the matching URL strings and an action which in your case is a `Rewrite`.

Comment: I want redirect from image to web page